# Python: how to keep lists with specific values?

Tags: python, list

I have list of lists like the following:

myList1

```
[[1, 7, 0],
 [0, 7, 1],
 [3, 2],
 [2, 9, 3],
 [4],
 [6, 10, 11, 5],
 [5, 10, 11, 12, 6],
 [0, 1, 7],
 [14, 15, 8],
 [3, 16, 9],
 [5, 6, 11, 10],
 [5, 6, 10, 12, 11],
 [6, 11, 12],
 [18, 19, 20, 13],
 [8, 15, 14],
 [8, 14, 15],
 [9, 25, 16],
 [18, 26, 27, 17],
 [13, 17, 19, 26, 27, 28, 18],
 [13, 18, 20, 27, 28, 29, 19],
 [13, 19, 28, 29, 20],
 [30, 21],
 [23, 30, 31, 32, 22],
 [22, 24, 31, 32, 33, 23],
 [23, 32, 33, 34, 24],
 [16, 36, 37, 25],
 [17, 18, 27, 41, 26],
 [17, 18, 19, 26, 28, 41, 42, 27],
 [18, 19, 20, 27, 29, 41, 42, 28],
 [19, 20, 28, 42, 29]]
```

I want to keep the longest lists that contains all the repeated values.

For instance I have

```
[3, 2]
[2, 9, 3]
```

I want to keep `[2, 9, 3]`.

For instance I have:

```
[6, 10, 11, 5]
[5, 10, 11, 12, 6]
```

I want to keep only `[5, 10, 11, 12, 6]`.

If we have

```
 [17, 18, 27, 41, 26]
 [17, 18, 19, 26, 28, 41, 42, 27]
 [18, 19, 20, 27, 29, 41, 42, 28]
```

we should have only

```
[17,18, 19, 20, 26,  27, 29, 28, 41, 42]
```

This what I tried.

```
def getMaxList(L)
    maxl = dict()
    for vl in L:
        for v in vl:
            maxl[v] = max((maxl.get(v,[]),vl),key=len)  # {value:longest list}
    return [sl for sl in L if sl in map(maxl.get,sl)]

getMaxList(myList1)


[[1, 7, 0],
 [2, 9, 3],
 [4],
 [5, 10, 11, 12, 6],
 [14, 15, 8],
 [13, 17, 19, 26, 27, 28, 18],
 [30, 21],
 [23, 30, 31, 32, 22],
 [22, 24, 31, 32, 33, 23],
 [23, 32, 33, 34, 24],
 [16, 36, 37, 25],
 [17, 18, 19, 26, 28, 41, 42, 27],
 [18, 19, 20, 27, 29, 41, 42, 28]]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: does the order matter? I mean can `set` be used?

Comment: @Epsi95 the order does not matter

Comment: @ccarstens I tried a loop but it is not very performant

Comment: @AlainT. Sorry I made a mistake. Please check the returning list after the function `getMaxList(myList1)`

Answer (score 1):

After the latest update, you now seem to only want a set of unique values out of all the lists:

```
L=[[1, 7, 0], [0, 7, 1], [3, 2], [2, 9, 3], [4],
  [6, 10, 11, 5], [5, 10, 11, 12, 6], [0, 1, 7], [14, 15, 8],
  [3, 16, 9], [5, 6, 11, 10], [5, 6, 10, 12, 11], [6, 11, 12],
  [18, 19, 20, 13], [8, 15, 14], [8, 14, 15], [9, 25, 16],
  [18, 26, 27, 17], [13, 17, 19, 26, 27, 28, 18],
  [13, 18, 20, 27, 28, 29, 19], [13, 19, 28, 29, 20], [30, 21],
  [23, 30, 31, 32, 22], [22, 24, 31, 32, 33, 23], [23, 32, 33, 34, 24],
  [16, 36, 37, 25], [17, 18, 27, 41, 26], [17, 18, 19, 26, 28, 41, 42, 27],
  [18, 19, 20, 27, 29, 41, 42, 28], [19, 20, 28, 42, 29]]

r = list(set().union(*L))

print(r)    
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 
 36, 37, 41, 42]
```

Comment: I tried you method but it does not work properly. Please see the modified question with a different list.

Comment: the fact that I have two lists like  `[17, 18, 19, 26, 28, 41, 42, 27],
 [18, 19, 20, 27, 29, 41, 42, 28]` in which I have repeated values. I would like that the each value does not repeat trough the various lists. There should be just one list like: `[17,18, 19, 20, 26,  27, 29, 28, 41, 42]`

Comment: If that is the case, your first example should not have both [2,9,3] and [3,16,9] in the expected result.  Having no repeated values between the lists in the result will mean that you won't always have coverage of all values.  Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: Also, [17,18, 19, 20, 26,  27, 29, 28, 41, 42] is not one of the original lists. If you have merging rules, you should describe them in your problem statement.

Comment: we should only consider `myList1`. Please see the modified question

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

An efficient way can be use of Tree-like data structure. It actually traverses and creates the longest possible branch from the sorted list items.

```py
l = [[1, 7, 0],[0, 7, 1],[3, 2],[2, 9, 3],[4],[6, 10, 11, 5],[5, 10, 11,12, 6],[0, 1, 7],[14, 15, 8],[3, 16, 9]]

class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.children = []
        
class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Node(-1)
        
    def add_a_list(self, l):
        l = sorted(l)
        pin = None
        for each_child in self.root.children:
            if(l[0] == each_child.value):
                pin = each_child
                break
        if(pin == None):
            self.add_as_a_new_branch(l)
        else:
            self.add_with_existing_pin(pin, l[1:])
      
    def add_with_existing_pin(self, pin, l):
        if(len(l) == 0):
            return
        for each_child in pin.children:
            if(each_child.value == l[0]):
                self.add_with_existing_pin(each_child, l[1:])
                return
            
        sc = Node(l[0])
        pin.children.append(sc)
        if(len(l) == 1):
            return
        current = sc
        for i in l[1:]:
            tt = Node(i)
            current.children.append(tt)
            current = tt
            
    def add_as_a_new_branch(self, l):
        rt = Node(l[0])
        self.root.children.append(rt)
        if(len(l) == 1):
            return
        current = rt
        for i in l[1:]:
            tt = Node(i)
            current.children.append(tt)
            current = tt
            
    def gb(self):
        output = []
        self.generate_branches(self.root, output, [])
        return output
            
    def generate_branches(self, r, output, prev):
        for each_child in r.children:
            each_child.till_now = prev
            #print(each_child.value, prev, [i.value for i in each_child.children])
            if(len(each_child.children) == 0):
                output.append([*each_child.till_now, each_child.value])
            else:
                self.generate_branches(each_child, output, [*each_child.till_now, each_child.value])
                
                
                
t = Tree()

for i in l:
    t.add_a_list(i)
    
result = t.gb()

print(result)
```

```
[[0, 1, 7], [2, 3, 9], [4], [5, 6, 10, 11, 12], [8, 14, 15], [3, 9, 16]]
```

---

**OLD**

I am skeptical about the efficiency though. It is already O(m*n). But you can give it a try

```py
l = [[1, 7, 0],[0, 7, 1],[3, 2],[2, 9, 3],[4],[6, 10, 11, 5],[5, 10, 11,12, 6],[0, 1, 7],[14, 15, 8],[3, 16, 9]]

l = sorted(l, key=lambda x: len(x)) # sorting to make sure supersets are on right hand side
output = [set(l[0])] # setting the first list element as first element of output

for i in l[1:]:
    # this variable will keep track if i is not a superset
    # of any of the output elements
    not_a_single_super_set = True
    for index, j in enumerate(output):
        if(set(i).issuperset(j)):
            output[index] = set(i)
            not_a_single_super_set = False
            break
    if(not_a_single_super_set):
        output.append(set(i))
            
print(output)
```

```
[{4}, 
{9, 2, 3}, 
{0, 1, 7}, 
{8, 14, 15}, 
{16, 9, 3}, 
{5, 6, 10, 11, 12}]
```